# AnyLogic Chat Call Center Model

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to model a Call Center with Chat communication and need your thoughts on this scenario. Real world scenario is that Customer Service Representatives[CSR] in Chat Call Center can service multiple customer chats at same time based on their capacity[integer value 1,2...]

1. "Chat" Agent [source]
2. "ChatAgent" resource unit with int parameters totalCapacity[default=3]

Using a service, incoming "Chat" from source seizes a "ChatAgent" from a resourcePool[with resourceUnit "ChatAgent"]. In this model, a "ChatAgent" accepts only 1 "Chat" inside the service block.

ResourcePool
On seize: unit.totalCapacity--;
On release: unit.totalCapacity++;

But I couldn't model a scenario where 1 "ChatAgent" can service multiple customer "Chats" at a time based on their totalCapacity like in a real chat call center.

Please advise on how I can configure this multiple agents to 1 resource seize/delay.

[Updated Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmbLT.png)

[Updated ChatAgent Resource Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A63Qt.png)

Thanks,
Shiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways of doing this, but the first thing that comes to mind is NOT to use ChatAgent as a resource (at least not the kind you use on a service block) because chats can come at any given time, and you can't have a resource taking many different agents that come at different times through the service block...

Instead you can use the following structure in the chatAgent:
[image: ChatAgent Structure]

The capacity of the resource will define how many agents can enter the restrictedArea block... This structure will exist inside your chatAgent resource.

Your main agent will have the following structure:
[image: main structure]

when the chat waits for an available chatAgent, if a chatAgent is available by doing:

```
chatAgent.beginService.entitiesInside() < chatAgent.capacity
```

These are the most important details to make it work... now you have to build the model properly.

Comment: Updated new model "screenshot with restrictedArea block" to the question. On resourcePool of ChatAgents seize: ((ChatAgent)unit).totalCapacity--; and on release ((ChatAgent)unit).totalCapacity--;  Request clarification on how to use agent.totalCapacity[value=3] to have 3 chats at a time in the delay block and then gets released.

Comment: as I said in my answer.. you don't use resources so seize and release don't exist.. but i also interpreted that the chats can come independently... if they come together as a batch, then the answer would be different

Comment: "ChatAgent" resource now has totalCapacity variable and restricted block structure as above with reference to "Chat" object[screenshot attached]. Source object contains incoming chats independently. With these 2 new agents - Chat and ChatAgent[resource], do I need a Service object to bring these 2 objects together? I am new to AnyLogic and sincerely apologize if my request for clarifications are irrelevant. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i updated my answer, hopefully you will understand it better

Comment: ChatAgent [totalCapacity + restrictedArea start/end block with agent Type as "Chat"]. In the sample main flow, "Chat" entities inside the "ChatAgent" resource remains 0. For instance from "chatArrivals" source block I am passing the "Chat" agents and in "toChatAgent"[agent type ChatAgent] exit block chatAgent.beginService.entitiesInside() returns 0. Please let me know if the agent type I am using in blocks are incorrect.

Comment: I created the model for you... the restricted area are not really necessary... download the model here: https://ufile.io/px4uf

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have created my model based on the model logic you have provided and customized based on my requirements.